# how to sum up the query execution timing in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I ran thousands of query, now I want to record the all timing results. But the thing is for thousands query there are thousands timing in millisecond. So I just wanna sum up the total time of those millisecond. So how should I do that.

I used db.setProfilingLevel(2), then used db.system.profile.find({op:"query"}) to get the timings. the results are

```
{ "ts" : ISODate("2014-04-15T13:05:08.434Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "practice.students", "query" : { "CID" : 55217 }, "nscanned" : 1000, "nreturned" : 1, "responseLength" : 53, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2014-04-15T13:05:08.472Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "practice.students", "query" : { "CID" : 152120 }, "nscanned" : 1000, "nreturned" : 1, "responseLength" : 54, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
```

So I want to sum the millis field, how should I do that, can some please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) command for any type of analysis, just like on any other collection:

```js
db.system.profile.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "op": "query" }},
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "millis": { "$sum": "$millis" } }}
])
```

And even quite a lot more by using the various [framework operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).